# Are gnome shortcut keys case-sensitive?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, case-sensitivity

I've noticed some inconsistency in case sensitivity of gnome shortcuts and am looking for some help and clarification...

From what I can tell, shortcuts are case-sensitive but must be assigned (using the settings GUI) with the upper case version **first**.
For example, I can not assign <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> as shortcuts but if  I do them in the opposite order I can do this.
(I've confirmed this isn't due to a conflict by dumping `dconf` and grepping for the bindings.)

However, if I use the terminal to assign a shortcut (a la `dconf write KEY VALUE`) to set a shortcut, I *CAN* assign shortcuts in any order so I'm guessing this just has to do with how the GUI interprets the key input.t][

Further, it seems that some web-app specific shortcuts will conflict with system-wide shortcuts due to case insensitivity. For example, google slides/docs: increase font size with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> will conflict with a system keyboard shortcut of <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>  But if I disable the system-wide shortcut  I can use the web-app shortcut without issue.

1. Do any other users experience the same thing? (gnome 3.32)
2. Is there anyway to strictly enforce case-sensitivity in shortcuts?